# Attach metadata for the json that rest framework returns

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

I have the model named `station` and made API according to `django rest framework`.

```
class Station(models.Model):
    filter_class = StationFilter
    name = models.CharField(unique=True,max_length=255)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class StationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Station
        fields = ('id','name')

class StationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Station.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StationSerializer
```

Now, It returns the Json like this correspond to the cols of table.

```
{
    [ 
        {id: 1,name:"station1"},
        {id: 2,name:"station2"}
    ]
}
```

However I want to attach metadata for this Json like this.

```
{
    meta : {'time':"2020-02-02 00:00:00:",'apiName:"myapi"},
    items :[ 
        {id: 1,name:"station1"},
        {id: 2,name:"station2"}
    ]
}
```

Is it possible? or how can I make it??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to override the `list` method of your `ViewSet`:

```
class StationViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    ...

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        custom_data = {
            'list_of_items': StationSerializer(self.get_queryset(), many=true).data  #     this is the default result
        }
        custom_data.update({
            'meta': #your extra data
        })
        return Response(custom_data)
```

**Update:**

As you added Filtering to your `ModelViewSet`, you should do something like this:

```
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
    custom_data = {
        'list_of_items': self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True).data
    }
    custom_data.update({
        'meta': #your extra data
    })
    return Response(custom_data)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It saves me!! One more question..., can I ask a one more question?? I used filter. but when I override list , these classes dosen't work. (updated article) –

Comment: @whitebear I updated the answer, hopes it working for you.